# Angular JS ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

**[Working DEMO with Single List](https://plnkr.co/edit/LAQARFbCJHVZSaXaWWU0?p=preview)**

Edit : Trying to Add Code Snippet IN JSON to Display in Front END as attached in the image.

can you please advice can we add ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2LOs.png

i have a list of data that has to be displayed in Listing, as of now i only have one object and only one li can add

can we render object in side a object just like this, i tried there is error.

```
"list":{
          {"object":"1"},
          {"object":"2"},
          {"object":"3"},
          {"object":"4"},
          {"object":"5"}
        }
```

JSON :

```
    [
    {
        "title"         :   "JavaScript ?",
        "description"   :   "Hey, here are some of the merits of javascript",
        "list"          :   "JavaScript is very easy to implement. All you need to do is put your code in the HTML document and tell the browser that it is JavaScript.",
        "uploadedDate"  :   "April 12 2015",
        "tags"          :   "javascript, webdevelopment"
    }
    ]
```

JS :

```
var app = angular.module("jsBlogApp", []);


//Menu 
app.service("headerMenu", function($http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('json/headerMenu.json').then(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    this.getMenuItems = function (){
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
.controller("headerMenuCtrl", function($scope, headerMenu){
    var promise = headerMenu.getMenuItems();
    promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.headerMenuItems = data.data;
        console.log($scope.headerMenuItems);
    })
})


// Secondary Menu
app.service("secondaryHeaderMenu", function($http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('json/secondaryHeaderMenu.json').then(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    this.getSecondaryMenuItems = function (){
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
.controller("SecondaryheaderMenuCtrl", function($scope, secondaryHeaderMenu){
    var promise = secondaryHeaderMenu.getSecondaryMenuItems();
    promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.SecondaryMenuItems = data.data;
        console.log($scope.SecondaryMenuItems);
    })
})




app.service("jsBlogService", function($http, $q) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get('json/data.json').then(function(data){
        deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    this.getPlayers = function (){
        return deferred.promise;
    }
})
.controller("jsBlogCtrl", function($scope, jsBlogService){
    var promise = jsBlogService.getPlayers();
    promise.then(function(data){
        $scope.items = data.data;
        console.log($scope.items);
    })
})
```

HTML :

{{menu.title}}

```
        <div class="second__header">
            <div class="second__header__wrap clearfix">
                <div class="js__logo__wrap">
                    <h1 class="js__logo">JS Developer</h1>
                    <div class="js__logo__subtitle">~ codeJS </div>
                </div>

                <div class="c2f__nav__wrap" data-ng-controller="SecondaryheaderMenuCtrl">
                    <ul class="c2f__nav">
                        <li data-ng-repeat="menu in SecondaryMenuItems">
                            <a href="{{menu.link}}">{{menu.title}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </header>

    <section class="c2f__content clearfix">
        <div class="c2f__cont_left">
            <!--content starts-->
            <div class="content__wrap" data-ng-controller="jsBlogCtrl">
                <div data-ng-repeat="item in items">
                    <h2 class="title__head"> {{ item.title }}</h2>
                    <p class="desc__head">{{ item.description }}</p>
                    <p>Listing
                        <ul class="data__lisitng">
                            <li>
                                <span>{{ item.list }}</span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </p>


                    <div class="code"></div>

                    <span class="content__added__date">
                        {{ item.uploadedDate }}
                    </span>
                    <span class="content__tags">
                        <span class="tags__links__title">Tags - </span>
                        <span class="tags__links__desc">{{ item.tags }}</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
    </footer>

</div>
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you try to get a list with objects or .. ?

Comment: var list = {
    $scope.yourItems;
};

Comment: Working DEMO with single LI - https://plnkr.co/edit/LAQARFbCJHVZSaXaWWU0?p=preview

Comment: You question isn't clear.  It seems like you want to iterate through "list", which needs to be a collection not an object, yet your HTML doesn't show the ng-repeat on "list".  Confusing ...

Comment: Your demo still works perfectly when I add another item: https://plnkr.co/edit/8TLDTV0OtE10hITr9Vf9?p=preview

Comment: @Matheno : i mean List (object ) should be multiple

Comment: I added a working plunkr in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I finally get what you were trying:

Here is a working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/8TLDTV0OtE10hITr9Vf9?p=preview

JSON

```
[
{
    "title"         :   "JavaScript ?",
    "description"   :   "Hey, here are some of the merits of javascript",
    "list"          :   [
    {
        "subtitle":"subtitle1",
        "message":"message1"
    },
    {
         "subtitle":"subtitle2",
        "message":"message2"
    }
  ] ,
    "uploadedDate"  :   "April 12 2015",
    "tags"          :   "javascript, webdevelopment"
}
]
```

HTML

```
          <div class="content__wrap" data-ng-controller="jsBlogCtrl">
            <div data-ng-repeat="item in items">
              <h2 class="title__head"> {{ item.title }}</h2>
              <p class="desc__head">{{ item.description }}</p>
              <p>Listing
                                </p>
              <ul class="data__lisitng">
                <li ng-repeat="message in item.list">
                  <span>{{ message.message }}</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <p></p>
              <div class="code"></div>
              <span class="content__added__date">
                                {{ item.uploadedDate }}
                            </span>
              <span class="content__tags">
                <span class="tags__links__title">Tags - </span>
                <span class="tags__links__desc">{{ item.tags }}</span>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Exactly.. Thanks heaps :-)

Comment: Heh, glad someone could figure out what was wanted. I personally tried to figure out what was wanted but didn't quite get there. Have a upvote!

Answer (score 1):

At least the list should be like this instead:

```
"list":[
  {"object":"1"},
  {"object":"2"},
  {"object":"3"},
  {"object":"4"},
  {"object":"5"}
];
```

I would prefer something like:

```
$scope.list = [
  {"object":"1"},
  {"object":"2"},
  {"object":"3"},
  {"object":"4"},
  {"object":"5"}
];
```

Comment: its a seprate json file

Comment: Well I could only tell you where an error occurs based on your question :)

Answer (score 1):

use '[' instead of '{'

```
     [
      {"object":"1"},
      {"object":"2"},
      {"object":"3"},
      {"object":"4"},
      {"object":"5"}
     ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"list":{
      {"object":"1"},
      {"object":"2"},
      {"object":"3"},
      {"object":"4"},
      {"object":"5"}
    }
```

is not valid. Please use a valid object/array for ng-repeat

Comment: If you like to post an answer, then please update your answer with something to help them. For example the right syntax.

Comment: Thanks! Thepio's answer speaks about the right syntax.